# How can I remove key: pairs over a certain number from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

Given a number and an dictionary, "remove_numbers_larger_than" removes any keys whose values are numbers greater than the given number. Return the modified dictionary.

```
def remove_numbers_larger_than(dictionary, number):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if v > number:
            del d[k]
    return dictionary
```

Comment: `def remove_numbers_larger_than(d, n): return {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v <= n}`

Answer (score 3):

If you are required to modify the given `dict` in place, make a copy of the keys first, so that removing keys from the dict doesn't interfere with iteration.

```
def remove_numbers_larger_than(dictionary, number):
    keys = list(dictionary)
    for k in keys:
        if dictionary[k] > number:
            del dictionary[k]
    return dictionary
```

If you are free to create a new `dict` instead,

```
def remove_numbers_larger_than(dictionary, number):
    return dict(kv for kv in dictionary.items() if kv[1] <= number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet, it will loop over the dictionary, selects numbers that are smaller than or equal to given number and creates a new dictionary with selected numbers.

```py
def remove_numbers_larger_than(dictionary, number):
    return { key: dictionary[key] for key in dictionary if dictionary[key] <= number }
```

Answer (score 0):

The in-place method could be simplified a little bit. The whole dict is iterated over only once and the auxilliary list holds only the offending keys, not all keys.

```
for k in [k for k, v in dictionary.items() if v > number]:
    del dictionary[k]
```